# EntityFramework: Reusability of '.Where' clauses for nested data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The example is as follows: I have a database with all kinds of information about code reviews: reviewers, file infos, revision infos, ... I am using Entity Framework for data access. With regards to that, I have following models (simplified):

```
public class ReviewItem {
    public virtual ICollection<ExpandedRevision> ExpandedRevisions { get; set; }
    public virtual int? AuthorId { get; set; }
}

// ...

public class ExpandedRevision {
    public int ChangedLines { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get the total number of changed lines that a particular user reviewed. I do it like that:

```
public int GetLinesReviewed(int userId) {
    using (var ctx = new CrucibleDBContext()) {
        return ctx.ReviewItems
            .Include(file => file.ExpandedRevisions)
            .Where(file => file.AuthorId == userId)
            .Sum(file => file
                    .ExpandedRevisions
                    .Where(er => !er.FilePath.Contains("third party") &&
                        !er.FilePath.Contains("ThirdParty")
                    )
                    .Sum(er => er.ChangedLines)
            });
    }
}
```

So the most interesting part in the above example is this:

```
.Where(er => !er.Path.Contains("third party") &&
    !er.Path.Contains("ThirdParty")
)
```

Remembering that this is a simplified example, there are actually much more lines there.

I need such piece of code in a lot of places, so what I tried to do is to create a function that will encapsulate and centralize this logic. But due to the fact that `ExpandedRevisions` is declared as `ICollection<ExpandedRevision>`, the compiler does not allow me to pass `Expression<Func<ExpandedRevision, bool>>` there, but only `Func<ExpandedRevision, bool>`. That results in materialization of the whole thing, which is obviously something I don't want.

Question: how do I achieve code reusability in this case without having to load all the things into memory?

Comment: The problem and a possible solution is explained [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: thx, @IvanStoev, that's definitely something worth taking a look at. Although I was under the impression that EF is mature enough to have in-built support for such cases.